# How to unjar a jar file with default package?

Tags: java, jar

With ref. to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html

I have a jar file with the default package that I downloaded and it doesn't unzip with:

```
jar -xf stdlib.jar
```

and there is no special mention of such a case on the official docs. Even 7Zip doesn't help as it says "Cant open the file as archive".

So how do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

JAR is compressed using ZIP, as per [JAR (file format) wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)):

> They are built on the ZIP format and typically have a .jar file extension.

If `jar xf`, `unzip` or other standard ZIP extractor command doesn't work then the JAR archive is corrupted.

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong bro . i mean i can even give you the jarfile . Netbeans recognizes the classes in it, but `jar xf` doesn't unzip them. My problem is not solved .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it's permission, the file might be with the wrong set-up.